# ZIP archive comment

Tags: zip

Currently I'm developing a minimalist ZIP 2.0 library.

In keeping with the motto "Read the f*ckin' manual!", I read PKWARE's [appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-2.0.txt), so I know a ZIP archive containing only the "end of central directory record" is considered empty. This record defines a variable size "archive comment" in the end, which is why one has to scan backwards in search for the signature "PK\5\6" when loading the central directory. This leaves me with two questions:

1) What should I do when the user tries to add an archive comment containing this sequence?

2) Is an empty archive allowed to have a comment? (WinRAR isn't able to show it when the archive is empty while 7-Zip is)

UPDATE:

I have had email contact with Mr Roshal, lead developer of WinRAR. He confirmed 2) to be a bug in WinRAR that is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP file format does not specify what is valid for the content of a file comment or zipfile comment. In one place their documentation describes the comment as "text information", but elsewhere, the comment is described as "bytes of data", and the appnote itself doesn't say anything about what can go in a comment.

However, even if the spec *does* allow arbitrary binary data in a comment, that doesn't mean that you have to allow it using your library, and if you choose to allow it, that doesn't mean you have to make it easy.

So, here's a list of possible ways of handling the comment. Choose one.

1. Refuse to allow binary data in comments.
2. Allow binary data, but refuse to allow the specific signature.
3. Allow arbitrary binary data, but require the user to provide some sort of extra confirmation, if they try to include the signature.
4. Allow arbitrary binary data, don't worry about the signature.

Of course, for any option where imbedding the signature is possible, the documentation should warn the user that doing this will result in an invalid ZIP file.